# Having difficulty parsing date and time together Android

Tags: java, android

I need help parsing this string of data and time. Could any one help me fix my format or give guidance? Thanks.

2016-04-23T01:00:00Z

```
    SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:dd:yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat hour = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    String yearParse = year.format(Date.parse(year));
    String hourParse = hour.format(Date.parse(hour));
```

Comment: what is 06:00??? can you clear

Comment: I am unsure, to be frank. It is the data im json parsing in..

Comment: you can check my answer !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102313/discussion-between-punit-sharma-and-mike-m).

Comment: but in respect to the current , its right !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this methods to get Date and Time in format you wants

For **Date**

```
  public static String getDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date parsed = null;
    try {
        parsed = sourceFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
     return formatter.format(parsed);
  }
```

For **Time**

```
public static String getTime(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date parsed = null;
    try {
        parsed = sourceFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
     return formatter.format(parsed);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1= new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2= new SimpleDateFormat("hh-mm-ss");
String year=sdf1.format(required_date);
String hour=sdf2.format(required_date);
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: 2016-04-23T01:00:00Z  is the error I am getting with this. What I am doing is doing the parsing for a toString method.

Comment: what are you putting as required_date?